# Angular binding is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to angular. I have created a HTML where the user enters anything into the text box, and at the same time it should appear on the screen whatever you have input to the text box.

HTML CODE:

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <title>Hello World - AngularJS</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    Write some text in textbox:
    <input type="text" ng-model="sometext" />

    <h1>Hello {{ sometext }}</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you forget `ng-controller`

Comment: Your code is working perfectly..see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/dhtrL55q/)

Comment: please check your browser console for errors..

Comment: and also check angular version

Comment: @Grundy I dont think he has to do a recheck in his angular version as I used the same version as his in the fiddle and it worked well..

Comment: @Lal, oh, missed that in post full version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely write out the source

```
<head>
    <title>Hello World - AngularJS</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

Comment: That is not actually needed..what the OP has done is enough..It works really well.

Comment: Aye; if he's running the file with the `file://`-protocol, it will not be able to resolve `file://ajax.googleapis.com[...]` and nothing will work. @Lal if OP is opening the HTML-file in a web browser (and not running a web-server). It will not work with just `//ajax.googleapis.com[...]`...